# A way to integrate MySQL and SAP?

Tags: php, mysql, integration

I already have a working PHP form which stores data on MySQL database. Is it possible to store the same data on SAP? Like submit once then update both MySQL and SAP?

Comment: SAP is a huge software company. It depends which SAP software you are talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible many ways:

1. With SAP RFC connection protocol: https://github.com/piersharding/php-sapnwrfc
2. With web-services or files (IDocs, plain texts)
3. With direct access to some scheme of SAP's DB (in many cases it's prohibited)

But I'm warning you that SAP is not RDBMS. It's application server; it has some API and you have to call some predefined methods.

For your case SAP RFC and BAPI are good ways.